# Tikz: how to plot arcsec and arccos?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

It is easy to plot arctan and arccot, but got inverse sec and csc functions, It seems difficult. Can anyone do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us the complete but minimal code of how you are plotting an arctan-function. Like this we will know, what packages you are using and we do not have to type everything in order to add one function. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Using the `pgfplots` package, which makes plotting with TikZ easy, something as simple as

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain = -1:1, samples = 500]
    \addplot[color = red]  {asin(x)};
    \addplot[color = blue] {acos(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

works nicely

[image]

Notice that you need to restrict the domain of the function to something sensible ([-1,1]) and to get a smooth curve to have enough samples (points calculated in the range used). Also notice that the PGF maths engine works in degrees: you could of course convert the *y*-axis to radians if required (the question does not specify this).

For *e.g.* inverse secant the obvious apporach is to use standard identities (see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsecant) and to again pick appropriate domains but in 'parts'. For example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[samples = 500]
    \addplot[domain = -10:-1, color = red] {acos(1/x)};
    \addplot[domain = 1:10, color = red]   {acos(1/x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

which is a plot of the inverse secant function over a hopefully-useful range.

Comment: Thank you! Just hope one day we can plot directly by using tikz...

Comment: @user145722 It's not unique to PGF that the end user is expected to use some identities to use more 'advanced' trigonometric functions based on more 'basic' ones (for example, my calculator will handle sine/cosine/tangent happily but not secant!).

Comment: We do have `asec` and `acsc` in LaTeX3's `l3fp`, since it wasn't too hard to add.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I'm sure we do :-) My point was that it's not anything like as much as a necessity as cos/sin/tan and the inverses.

Answer (score 8):

This answer was prepared for you long time ago.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\FPeval\XMin{0-5}
\FPeval\XMax{5}
\FPeval\YMin{0-pi/3}
\FPeval\YMax{pi}

\FPeval\XOL{0-1/3} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\XOR{1/3} % of DeltaX
\FPeval\YOB{0-1/3} % of DeltaY
\FPeval\YOT{1/3} % of DeltaY

\FPset\TrigLabelBase{3}
\FPeval\DeltaX{1}
\FPeval\DeltaY{pi/TrigLabelBase}

\FPeval\AxisL{XMin+DeltaX*XOL}
\FPeval\AxisR{XMax+DeltaX*XOR}
\FPeval\AxisB{YMin+DeltaY*YOB}
\FPeval\AxisT{YMax+DeltaY*YOT}

\newlength\Width\Width=12cm
\newlength\Height\Height=8cm

\newlength\llx\llx=-5pt
\newlength\urx\urx=15pt
\newlength\lly\lly=-5pt
\newlength\ury\ury=15pt


\psset
{
    llx=\llx,
    lly=\lly,
    urx=\urx,
    ury=\ury,
    xtrigLabels=false,
    ytrigLabels=true,
    trigLabelBase=\TrigLabelBase,
    labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    algebraic,
    plotpoints=500,
}

\def\f{acos(1/x)}
\def\g{acos(x)}

\begin{document}
\pslegend[lt]{%
    \color{NavyBlue}\rule{12pt}{1pt} & \color{NavyBlue} $y=\sec^{-1} x$\\
    \color{Red}\rule{12pt}{1pt} & \color{Red} $y=\cos^{-1} x$
}
\begin{psgraph}
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        linecolor=gray,
        tickcolor=gray,
        ticksize=-3pt 3pt,
        axespos=top,
    ]{<->}(0,0)(\AxisL,\AxisB)(\AxisR,\AxisT){\dimexpr\Width-\urx+\llx}{!}%{\dimexpr\Height-\ury+\lly}
    \psaxes
    [
        dx=\DeltaX,
        dy=\DeltaY,
        labels=none,
        subticks=5,
        tickwidth=.4pt,
        subtickwidth=.2pt,
        tickcolor=Red!30,
        subtickcolor=ForestGreen!30,
        xticksize=\YMin\space \YMax,
        yticksize=\XMin\space \XMax,
        subticksize=1,
    ](0,0)(\XMin,\YMin)(\XMax,\YMax)
    \psplot[linecolor=NavyBlue]{-5}{-1}{\f}
    \psplot[linecolor=NavyBlue]{1}{5}{\f}
    \psplot[linecolor=Red]{-1}{1}{\g}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Documentation

[image]

No need to load `pst-math` as `pst-plot` has defined the following functions.

- `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, `acos`, `asin` are in radians
- `log`, `ln`
- `ceiling`, `floor`, `truncate`, `round`
- `sqrt` (square root)
- `abs` (absolute value)
- `fact` (factorial)
- `Sum`
- `IfTE` (case structure)

Comment: `XOR`, `XOL`, `YOT`, `YOB` are offsets which are multiple of `DeltaX` and `DeltaY`, respectively. They are important to make the axes look more exotic (IMHO).

Comment: Please, never use `\sec^{-1}` and `\cos^{-1}` since there are no inverses of these functions. As a mathematician, my heart is missing a beat every time I see something like that. You should use `\arcsec` and `\arccos` instead. Sorry for nitpicking, but I'm caring for my health ... ;-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: But if we restrict its domain then the inverse is available. As a layman, I have no idea what `\arcsec` (and `arccos`) differs from `\sec^{-1}` (and `\cos^{-1}`), could you elaborate more? In my mind, they are just different in notation. Probably you are talking about reciprocal rather than inverse. :-)

Comment: Yes, if we restrict the domain, then there is an inverse. But restricting the inverse means creating a new function which differs from the old function by its domain of definition. That's why it's called `arccos` because it's defined as inverse of the restricted `cos` (not of `cos` defined on the set of real numbers which is the usual domain). I use to torture my students with that difference ;-)

Comment: By chance, somebody stumbled over this point today, i.e. that `sin` has no inverse. See my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194204/how-to-locally-specify-function-range-in-math-expression/194242#194242

Answer (score 5):

Needs an up-to-date `pst-math.pro` (TL 2014) or replace `ASEC(x)` with `ACOS(1/x)` and `ACSC(x)` with `ASIN(1/x)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-2)(5,4)
\psaxes[ytrigLabels,trigLabelBase=2,dy=1.57]{->}(0,0)(-5,-2)(5,4)
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt,algebraic}
\psplot[linecolor=cyan,arrows=-*,algebraic]{-5}{-1}{ASEC(x)}
\psplot[linecolor=cyan,arrows=*-]{1}{5}{ASEC(x)}
\psplot[linecolor=magenta,arrows=-*]{-5}{-1}{ACSC(x)}
\psplot[linecolor=magenta,arrows=*-]{1}{5}{ACSC(x)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Run it with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, actually I am trying to not use dvips->ps2pdf, just use PDFLatex. Eps figures driving me crazy. So that why I am trying to use PDFLatex for everything. Tikz works well with PDFLatex

Comment: As I already mentioned use `xelatex` it has some more advantages than `pdflatex`