# How to locally specify function range in math expression

Tags: coordinates

I'm creating simple coordinate transformation in order to define `\tdplotsetcoord` coordinates at Cartesian coord. system.
**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=3.85mm,z=-1cm]
\draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=1.2]},very thick] (-2,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=north,xshift=-3pt] {$x$}; 
\draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=1.2]},very thick] (0,-2,0) -- (0,5,0) node[anchor=west] {$y$};
\draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=1.2]},very thick] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,5) node[anchor=south] {$z$};
\def\Xx{-2} \def\Xy{1} \def\Xz{4}
\tdplotsetcoord{X}{sqrt((\Xx)^(2) + (\Xy)^(2) + (\Xz)^(2))}{acos(\Xz/(sqrt((\Xx)^(2) + (\Xy)^(2) + (\Xz)^(2))))}{asin(\Xy/(sqrt((\Xx)^(2) + (\Xy)^(2))))} % {ρ}{θ}{Φ}
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=1.5,width=3pt]},color=gray,semithick] (0,0,0) -- (X);
\draw[dashed,color=red] (0,0,0) -- (Xxy);
\draw[dashed,color=red] (Xxy) -- (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Spherical coordinates `radius ρ` and `polar angle θ` work fine (operate in their entire ranges), however `asimuthal angle Φ` apparently does not - it handles negative `x` values in my CC as positive. Thus every coordinate transformed into SC has non-negative `x` value.
Also the problem may be in the range of `arcsine`. It perhaps operates just at part of total. I know I have to define wider range of `asin` dependently upon sign combinations of `x,y` in order to get total `asimuthal angle Φ` extent (`max - min = 2\pi`).
**Question 1:** I'm wondering how can I even find out default range of Latex`asin`.
**Question 2:** How can I (roughly) define the wider `arcsine` range I was talking about? I would like the code to be as simple as possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `arcsin` function has a range from `-pi/2` to `pi/2` in radians or `-90` to `90` in degrees. The later is used by the `pgf` package. That answers your first question.

To compute the polar angle (here better: azimuth) for a cartesian point `(x,y)`, you can use the following formula:

> [image]

The range of this polar angle is from `-pi` to `pi` or `-180` degrees to `180` degrees. One could add `360` degrees to the negative case to get positive values only, but that's irrelevant for the application.
In code, this gives:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=3.85mm,z=-1cm]
  \draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=1.2]},very thick] (-2,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=north,xshift=-3pt] {$x$};
  \draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=1.2]},very thick] (0,-2,0) -- (0,5,0) node[anchor=west] {$y$};
  \draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=1.2]},very thick] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,5) node[anchor=south] {$z$};
  \def\Xx{-2} \def\Xy{1} \def\Xz{4}
  %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\radius{sqrt(\Xx*\Xx + \Xy*\Xy + \Xz*\Xz)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\azimuth{acos(\Xx/sqrt(\Xx*\Xx+\Xy*\Xy))}% part 1
  \pgfmathsetmacro\azimuth{ifthenelse(\Xy<0,-\azimuth,\azimuth)}% part 2
  \tdplotsetcoord{X}
    {\radius}
    {acos(\Xz/\radius)}
    {\azimuth}
  %
  \draw[-{Stealth[scale=1.5,width=3pt]},color=gray,semithick] (0,0,0) -- (X);
  \draw[dashed,color=red] (0,0,0) -- (Xxy);
  \draw[dashed,color=red] (Xxy) -- (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With that, the output is:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, `ifthenelse` is the command I was looking for. Just a remark- **in R3** the angle in `xy` plane is usually called asimuthal, no matter what character indicates that. Polar angle is the second one with `z` axis (`θ` in my specification).

Comment: If I can bother you once more:  
How can I quantify `arcsine` (or generally any other math expression) in Latex to find out the function range?

Comment: @user46581 You are right; I changed the angle name in the code to `\azimuth` now. The mathematical functions used in TikZ code are documented in the TikZ and PGF manual, but you will find no range description there. But I think you can trust that the usual definition(s) from a mathematical formulary are used internally. The only LaTeX way I know is inspecting the code directly (but a formulary should be enough).