# Ifthenelse variable equality

Tags: conditionals, pgfmath, coordinates

Last week I made simple coordinate transformation in order to define `\tdplotsetcoord` in Cartesian coord. system. My work and support of exp. user can be viewed [in this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194204/how-to-locally-specify-function-range-in-math-expression). The code looks as follows:

```
\def\Sx{0} \def\Sy{0} \def\Sz{-3}
\tdplotsetcoord{S}{sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2) + (\Sz)^(2))}{acos(\Sz/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2) + (\Sz)^(2))))}{ifthenelse(\Sy<0,-acos(\Sx/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2)))),acos(\Sx/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2)))))} % {radius}{polar}{asimuth}
```

However there is a problem with `(0,0,z)` Cartesian coordinates due to `zero` division in those math expressions. Also I'm trying to define transformation from zero C. coordinates manually using `ifthenelse` command:

**1)** Why `variable = 0` doesn't work? I'm getting `PGF Math Error: Unknown operator '=' or '=0'`. This is the example of `polar angle` transformation:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\polar{ifthenelse(\Sx=0 \AND \Sy=0 \AND \Sz=0,0,acos(\Sz/(sqrt(\Sx^(2) + \Sy^(2) + \Sz^(2)))))}
```

**2)** I failed also with `\equal` command getting bunch of errors ([log file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxA-dFcRfP61bHA2NFZFcTI3Vlk/edit?pli=1)). Can you show me the correct syntax? Thanks.

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\polar{ifthenelse(\equal{\Sx}{0} \AND \equal{\Sy}{0} \AND \equal{\Sz}{0},0,acos(\Sz/(sqrt(\Sx^(2) + \Sy^(2) + \Sz^(2)))))}
```

Edit: Working example does not differ from previous topic.
**MWE:**

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},x=3.85mm,z=-1cm]
    \draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=1.2]},thick] (-2,0,0) -- (5,0,0) node[anchor=north,xshift=-3pt] {$x$};
    \draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=1.2]},thick] (0,-2,0) -- (0,5,0) node[anchor=west] {$y$};
    \draw[-{Classical TikZ Rightarrow[scale=1.2]},thick] (0,0,-2) -- (0,0,5) node[anchor=south] {$z$};
    \def\Sx{0} \def\Sy{0} \def\Sz{-3}

% code without dealing with zero division
    \tdplotsetcoord{S}{sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2) + (\Sz)^(2))}{acos(\Sz/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2) + (\Sz)^(2))))}{ifthenelse(\Sy<0,-acos(\Sx/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2)))),acos(\Sx/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2)))))}

% code implementing zero coordinations definition
    \pgfmathsetmacro\polar{ifthenelse(\Sx=0 \AND \Sy=0 \AND \Sz=0,0,acos(\Sz/(sqrt(\Sx^(2) + \Sy^(2) + \Sz^(2)))))}
% plus asimuth angle zero definition...
    \tdplotsetcoord{S}{sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2) + (\Sz)^(2))}{\polar}{...}

    \draw[-{Stealth[scale=1.5,width=3pt]},color=red,thick] (0,0,0) -- (S) node[midway,anchor=east,font=\footnotesize] {${\vec{r}}_{1}$};
    \draw[dashed,color=red!70!white,semithick] (0,0,0) -- (Sxy);
    \draw[dashed,color=red!70!white,semithick] (Sxy) -- (S);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear from the code extracts if `ifthenelse` here should actually be `\ifthenelse` from the `ifthen` package. It will be much easier to help if you construct a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the issue.

Comment: I added MWE already

Comment: The MWE doesn't seem to feature the problem lines! However, what I do notice is that `pgf`'s `ifthenelse` keyword is for maths expressions only and uses `&&` for logical 'and', while the syntax you seem to be using is for the `\ifthenelse` macro from the `ifthen` package. Am I right in my understanding?

Comment: You are right. Using `&&` there remains just single error `PGF Math Error: Unknown operator '=' or '=0'` when implementing `\Sx=0 && \Sy=0 && \Sz=0`.  
Using `\equal{\Sx}{0} && \equal{\Sy}{0} && \equal{\Sz}{0}` there are still too much errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\polar{
   ifthenelse(\Sx=0 \AND \Sy=0 \AND \Sz=0,
     0,
     acos(\Sz/(sqrt(\Sx^(2) + \Sy^(2) + \Sz^(2)))))}
```

has several errors. The `ifthenelse` keyword implemented by `pgf` has a *different* syntax from the `\ifthenelse` macro from the `ifthen` package. You seem to be trying to mix the two, hence the issue. For the `ifthenelse` keyword, logical 'and' is denoted by `&&` and numerical equality by `==`. You also need to ensure that your squaring applies to the entirety of *e.g.* `\Sz` by adding parentheses:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\polar{
    ifthenelse(\Sx==0 && \Sy==0 && \Sz==0,
      0,
      acos(\Sz/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2) + (\Sy)^(2) + (\Sz)^(2)))))}
```

You also can't do text comparisons with the `ifthenelse` keyword, so `\EQUAL` is not applicable at all.

Comment: Thank you! Where did you namely find out the syntax? So I woudn't have to ask next time.

Comment: @user46581 Read [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) :-) In my copy, the key detail is on pages 932-933. (To get this for your installation, try `texdoc pgf` at the Command Line/Terminal.)

Answer (score 0):

Also the final code looks like this, for someone to facilitate his work:

```
\def\Sx{-2} \def\Sy{-3} \def\Sz{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sρ{"sqrt((\Sx)^(2)+(\Sy)^(2)+(\Sz)^(2))"}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Sθ{ifthenelse(\Sx==0&&\Sy==0&&\Sz==0,0,"acos(\Sz/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2)+(\Sy)^(2)+(\Sz)^(2))))")}
\pgfmathsetmacro\SΦ{ifthenelse(\Sx==0&&\Sy==0,0,ifthenelse(\Sy<0,"-acos(\Sx/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2)+(\Sy)^(2))))","acos(\Sx/(sqrt((\Sx)^(2)+(\Sy)^(2))))"))}
\tdplotsetcoord{S}{\Sρ}{\Sθ}{\SΦ}
```

Last three math expressions have to be returned as `"text strings"` (also it has to be done in another variable to evaluate them in `tdplotsetcoord`), otherwise `ifthenelse` command evaluates those expressions (->getting `zero division error`) even when second option is to return.